# track changes in a linq to sql object, which was passed over wcf (back and forth)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, linq-to-sql

I first get an object (here a object of the user class) per Linq to sql from the database.

```
dataacces da = new dataaccess(..);
user obj = da.users.First(o => od.id = 1);
```

then the user object is passed over wcf to a client, which for ex. changes the firstname property, and then passes the object back to the server for writing the changes to the database.

Is it possible to find out which properties did chance, compared to the entry in the database. The da.users.GetModifiedMembers(returned object of user) called on the returned user, gives me an empty array...

any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If the service is hosted on the one server, how about caching the object? Subsequent calls compares what came in with what's in cache.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reattach the modified entity once it's returned from the client:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548972.aspx